# How can I duplicate a point with matrix rotation every iteration?

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry, point

I have this code :

```cs
X1 = 0.5;
X2 = 0.3;
Y1 = 0.1;
Y2 = 0.4;


for(int i =0;i<20;i++) // let's suppose that we need to create 19 points from point A

{
    point1 = new System.Windows.Point((float)X1 , (float)Y1 );
    point2 = new System.Windows.Point((float)X2 , (float)Y2 );

    System.Windows.Point RotatedPoint = p1 * rotmatrix;
    System.Windows.Point RotatedPoint2 = p2 * rotmatrix;

    DrawingVisual d = new DrawingVisual();

    System.Windows.Media.Pen pen = new System.Windows.Media.Pen();

    DrawingContext drawingContext = d.RenderOpen();

    pen.Brush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;

    drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, point1 , point2 );

    drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, RotatedPoint, RotatedPoint2);

    drawingContext.Close();
    canvas.Children.Add(new VisualHost { Visual = d });
}
```

I would like to create a new point from original point with rotate it , as an example :

Let's suppose that I have a point called A , what I need exactly is created `B`, `C` and `D` ...

- `B` is the result point of A rotation .
- `C` is the result point of B rotation .

How can I do this?

Comment: It's unclear what your exact problem is. Is `Point B = A * rotmatrix; Point C = B * rotmatrix;` not what you want to do? If you'd tell us what your *actual goal* is, we might be able to suggest an appropriate solution.

Comment: Yes , What I need exactly is created in every iteration a new point that depends on the previous point , `new_point = previous_point * rotmatrix;`

Comment: And where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I didn't get what I need , I can only duplicate the original point , what I mean I can only duplicate A and get B ( rotation of A ) but I can't get the result of other points , note that the number of points is given by the user ( user input ).

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. You are asking how to rotate a given Point multiple times by the same Matrix, and at the same time you tell us about multiple Points from a list. How is that related? What do A, B and C have to do with the Points in your code sample. What is the code eventually supposed to do?

Comment: To explain exactly what I need , a point called A will be get copy to another A' and the second A will be rotated so the second is the B , now the same thing will be repeated created a copy of B called B' and rotate it , and than B' is the C .

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: You need to store the points of the previous iteration. I guess you want to overwrite X1, X2, Y1, Y2 in order to set the new strting points for the next iteration.

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion but I can't get what I need , could you please post an answer?